# What's the word for "Enable/Disable"?

Tags: naming-conventions, terminology

When I want to comment code about control Enable/Disable and when I want to discuss with people about the control Enable/Disable, I really hope there is actually a word to it instead of typing or saying "Enable/Disable".

Currently I use the word EnDisable, what is the real word of it?

Comment: If you mean controls, the common names are "ghost out" and "grey out"

Comment: In the context of writing a function or reporting a status: `SetEnabled` or `IsEnabled`.

Comment: This is not a question about programming! Maybe try https://english.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @U.Windl wouldn't Nomenclature be covered in programming; is not it extremely important (to standardize/add meaningful words to) the language which explains the code

Comment: @NicholasMiller: maybe your comment would justify an answer in this context, because it’s concise in function naming an also works with a “toggle” boolean.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I would suggest using "toggle" as although it doesn't exactly mean Enable/Disable it is commonly used as such in the context of user interfaces (as @Pekka mentioned).

Comment: I know this is old as hell but toggle typically describes turning something off/on, not controlling whether or not the control can be manipulated.

Answer (score 17):

I use "Ability", because if something is "enabled", it is "able to", and if it's "disabled" it is "unable to", so "ability" works for me and it's quite understandable.
To switch the parameter I name my function "setAbility".

Comment: I've settled on "Ability" myself, and I've found that there are times when it feels right to combine it with @Yacoby's answer and use "AbilityToggle".

Answer (score 13):

Really depends on the context.

- Changing of a control's status?
- Switch?
- Change?

Update: @Yacoby has the perfect one, it's widely used in user interface contexts.

Comment: "Change status" is exactly what I was looking for, since the code in question doesn't necessarily toggle between on/off

Answer (score 4):

If I'm writing functions that enable or disable something depending some other data, I usually call them "ToggleXXX".

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the context. If you are referring to a life-support system, 'Kill' probably.

Answer (score 1):

`Conditional` is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, but I would suggest **Behavior** if talking about whether something is enabled or disabled by default.

Other words like action, toggle, or condition can also work depending on the context

Comment: Behaviour is perfect for me when I needed the options `enable`, `disable` and `hidden`